# WPF: Give a ResourceDictionary a Name

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got a ResourceDictionary full of PathGeometry's for my Icons, is it possible I can give this ResourceDictionary a name so I can use some C# to view all of my Icons, and just to make things more grouped together?

So I would use one of the PathGeometry's like so for example

```
App.Current.Resources.Icons["refresh1"] as Geometry

or

App.Current.Resources["Icons"]["refresh1"] as Geometry
```

Currently I use `App.Current.Resources["refresh1"] as Geometry` to use one of the PathGeometry's.

Edit:
Unclear why this is, well, unclear. Poster below understood the question but was unclear in my reason for wanting to do this. However my reason isn't required, I just want an answer to what I'm asking, not a discussion on WHY do I want to do this.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What is the point in changing the code so that you have to write _more_ C# just to get at your resource? I.e. if you would normally write `App.Current.Resources["refresh1"]`, why do you want to have to arbitrarily require the addition of `.Icons` or `["Icons"]` to this? You certainly can have a named resource dictionary, of course, but not as part of the _existing_ `Resources` property (though it could be a resource itself, with the name as its key). What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I want the Icons to be under their own category, I know it's writing more, but I just prefer to group things. And I also want to loop through that category to display all Icons.

Comment: Then don't put them in the same `ResourceDictionary` with everything else. Either declare a `ResourceDictionary` as an element inside some object's `Resources` collection (i.e. exactly as you would any other object you wanted to access via `Resources`) or just declare it in code-behind. These strategies are obvious, which is why your question is unclear; since the obvious strategies are, well, obvious it's my assumption they don't work for you, but your question fails to explain why that would be or what different strategy would be considered useful by you.

Comment: Put another way: there's nothing in your question that helps us understand **what you've tried already**, nor a description of in what way what you've tried didn't work. Please provide a good [mcve] and description that clarifies these points.

Comment: Well, ... you edit is a bit rude. People are asking this, because WPF has many mechanisms that would make it unnecessary to do things like that. People are asking this, because you are probably trying to do something you do not need to or are not supposed to.

Comment: I see that is it a bit rude, and I'm sorry, but I get frustrated sometimes, as I see someone who knows what I want to know but doesn't answer the question but rather everyone questions why I'm doing it that way. I understand that it's a vast subject and they way I might be doing it is wrong, and I'm open for other ways and better ways. It just gets very frustrating when I have to have a discussion about something I want to do for usually a couple of days due to timezone differences until I actually get the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those very straightforward questions that people will spend more time arguing about than answering! :) People can argue the merit of it as much as they like but once you start doing things like dynamically loading ResourceDictionaries (say, from external plugin DLLs) topics like this suddenly become very relevant indeed!

To answer your question, yes, of course this is possible. The main caveat here is that if you just add ResourceDictionaries to your application resources dictionary then the XAML compiler will get confused about what you're trying to do. The trick here is to explicitly specify a single top-level ResourceDictionary and then add all your resources, including your key'd ResourceDictionaries, as the content of that:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dictionary1">
            <sys:String x:Key="str1a">String 1A</sys:String>
            <sys:String x:Key="str1b">String 1B</sys:String>
            <sys:String x:Key="str1c">String 1C</sys:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dictionary2">
            <sys:String x:Key="str2a">String 2A</sys:String>
            <sys:String x:Key="str2b">String 2B</sys:String>
            <sys:String x:Key="str2c">String 2C</sys:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <!-- All other application resources go here -->

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

Here's some XAML that statically binds to the dictionaries to show that this method works as intended:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource Dictionary1}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource Dictionary2}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image]

If you want to access the resources in code then you'll need to cast the first array lookup to a ResourceDictionary, then index that by the actual item key:

```
var str = (App.Current.Resources["Dictionary1"] as ResourceDictionary)["str1a"].ToString();
```

If that's too messy then you can clean it up with a helper class like so:

```
public class Global
{
    static Global _global = new Global();
    public static Global Dictionaries { get { return _global; } }

    public ResourceDictionary this[string index]
    {
        get { return App.Current.Resources[index] as ResourceDictionary; }
    }
}
```

Which you would then use like this:

```
var str = (string)Global.Dictionaries["Dictionary1"]["str1a"];
```

Comment: Thanks. The main purpose of this to be honest is so I can generate a List of the PathGeometry's within my ResourceDictionary so I can then populate a ListView with that List, mainly to help me have a graphical representation of the PathGeometry and it's name for use throughout the development.

Comment: Note to self, it's either or between nested ResourceDictionary's having an `x:Key` or being in a `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`